# Using standalone PHP files for Modals, great in Chrome, F/F... IE hides modal behind page

Tags: php

have been searching and searching for an answer or work-around.

I have several HTML pages which use various Modal Dialogs, for example, a "contact me" form.  Instead of including the modal code in each page, I've created a single file for each modal and tried to "include" or "require" in each HTML page.  Write once, use many or something like that.

It worked 100! in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE of any age.  IE loads up the main HTML, and also then the included / required Modal(s), but IE displays the main HTML but acts only on the modal.  Eg, modal is sitting in the background but can't be seen... Yes, I've played with the z-index in CSS..  Plumb out of ideas.  Probably something obvious? - Thanks in advance for any ideas...

Comment: @Alex, Hi, yes you're right, but it's nothing fancy...

<?php
include_once("contactMe.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html...

Comment: @Alex, right about both things...  :o)

Comment: Then this is not a PHP problem. Probably CSS/Javascript but as Alex asked before, we need to see your code in order to help.

Comment: And don't put anything before your `DOCTYPE` declaration. It's not correct HTML even if some browsers will accept it. It may even be the reason IE isn't cooperating :-).

Comment: 1) Confirm the browser mode in IE (press F12 to get dev tools which will show you the mode). If it's quirks mode or compatibility mode, you've found the problem. Fix is usually fairly simple. 2) Please confirm the IE version you're using. (it can make a very big difference, so I don't understand why so many questions don't mention it)